# Dimensions of momentum?

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, speed-of-light, dimensional-analysis, absolute-units

I am learning realitivity in college and in our class our lecturer explained four-momentum. When I was reading a book in QFT.
it writes the momentum as $p^{\mu} = (E,p^i)$. Why is one of the components energy? Energy and momentum have different dimensions
or is it different in quantum field theory?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, you are correct in that energy and momentum have different dimensions. What is actually happening is that
in the book you are reading, the author is using units (called "natural units") in which the speed of light $c=1$.

The momentum
four vector can be written explicitly as $\hat p = [\frac{E}{c},p_i]$.

Click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units) for more about natural units.

Answer (score 9):

It is common in QFT (and relativity in general) to use [natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#Natural_units_(particle_and_atomic_physics)) in which $c=1$.  In SI units, the 4-momentum takes the form $\mathbf p = (E/c, \vec p)$ where $\vec p = \gamma m \vec v$ is the 3-momentum.